# Azure Service Bus SessionId across multiple topics?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

ASB's SessionId can be used to guarantee ordering, for example if we have 5 messages which update an order, and 3 consumers running, the consumers won't process multiple messages for that order (SessionId = OrderId) at the same time.

But suppose I have 3 topics:

- CreateOrder
- UpdateOrder
- DeleteOrder

If there are X messages spread across these 3 topics, all with the same SessionId, would the consumers for each topic pay any attention to the SessionId being used by other topics?

As in, if a message were being consumed by a CreateOrder consumer with SessionId=5, would the UpdateOrder consumer wait for this lock to release before picking up one of its own messages with SessionId=5?

Comment: Is that you want to know the impact when the same session id in different topics?

Comment: You might word it like that, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sessions of different topics are independent and do not affect each other. In other words, when you receive messages with SessionId=1 in topic1, you also can receive messages with SessionId=2 in topic2. For more details, please refer to the official document [Azure Service Bus message sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions).
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to have ordered messages across multiple topics/queues? Example: User made a purchase two messages for two different queues was created 'OrderUpdated' and 'UserUpdated'. I need to be guaranteed that OrderUpdated is processed first.